# kernel patching - how to check / verify when specific patch was applied

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg, patch

How do I find/verify, IF and WHEN a specific patch for example [this one](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9645537/),  have been added to the kernel?

One way I can think off (not very efficient) would be to download all kernels since the patch was logged, and look into change log file. Example:

```
$ apt-get changelog linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic
```

How do you approach this type of problems?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45120/given-a-git-commit-hash-how-to-find-out-which-kernel-release-contains-it . There are several suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the a git clone of the source and search for the patch.
Mine is a clone of the mainline source from kernel.org:

```
git log --oneline | grep "add DISCARD support to virtio-blk driver"
```

did not find anything. As a sanity check, look at the code itself and manually observe if the patch was ever applied or not. I looked at `drivers/block/virtio_blk.c` and didn't see the patch.

Conclusion: the patch was never applied to the mainline kernel, and therefore I very much doubt that it would ever have been backported to previous kernels.

Comment: That seems like very good solution, thank you @doug-smythies